# How to Disable Terminal Bold Fonts?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal, fonts

I personally don't like Terminal bold fonts.

In previous versions of Ubuntu I was able to disable Terminal bold fonts using either a tick box in the Terminal preferences, or by disabling them using `dconf-editor`. Neither of these methods appear to be available in Ubuntu 20.04.

Any suggestions on how to disable Terminal bold fonts would be appreciated.

Comment: Preferences, Profiles: unnamed (or any other profile), Text tab? There you can set a custom font.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to change the font, just not have the selected font in bold for the terminal prompt and directory names, etc.